# How do I get the previous audio to stop when pressing the same button

Tags: javascript, flash, html5-canvas, html5-audio

First thing's first here's the entirety of my code so far, I am working on Adobe Animate (aka flash) with an HTML5 canvas. This is the final project for my class (professor gave it to us about 3 months early because of how big it is and encouraged us to use our peers as well as forums such as stackoverflow)

```
this.IntroButton.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame.bind(this));

function fl_ClickToGoToAndPlayFromFrame()
{
    
    this.Menu.visible = false;
    this.Intro.gotoAndPlay(2);
}
```

All that is happening here is that when I click the intro button, it makes the menu invisible and plays the intro I started animating all day yesterday. What I'm having trouble figuring out is how would I go about stopping the already playing audio, when I click the button again. The audio is attached to the to the movie clip that is the intro.

If you guys need more information please just let me know and I'll get that to you, thanks!

Comment: How is the audio playback actually started?

Comment: I figured it out, I just had to globally stop the audio, but if you're still wondering yes it had already started, what it was doing is it was just starting again without stopping the previous audio

Comment: Glad you figured it out! Stopping all audio is a possible solution of course. I'm still curious though - did you trigger the sound using the play() command?

Comment: @obsure Flash has a GUI with a timeline (since it also does animations). It's possible that the asker used the GUI to attach a `Sound` object into a `MovieClip` object. That variable `Intro` is like a _class_ with functions like _gotoAndPlay_ and likely holding the sound file / data as a variable. Also note the shown code is written like Actionscript (Flash's own language) but in the background it will be converted into HTML5 equivalents (_eg:_ in AS3 you declare a Sound object but that will magically become some Audio tag when the AS3 project is exported as HTML5). Just saying...

Comment: VC explained what I did perfectly, sorry for not explaining it too well, i've put about 12 hours into the project over the past couple days and am understandable, a little tired lol